# Unknown class in Interface Builder, migrating from xcode9 beta5 to xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

After migrating project from xcode9 beta 5 to xcode 8.3, I get the "uknown class in Interface Builder". Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846538/unknown-class-in-interface-builder

Comment: nah, it didn't help(: thanks though

Comment: What's the class's name supposed to be? What's the exact text of the error message? What's in the "module" field in Interface Builder? Is the class exposed to Objective-C? Is the class embedded within another type, or in the root namespace? We need more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Open the storyboard/XIB > look at the Identity Inspector (tab) > Custom Class section.

1. Class: Clear out the class and set it back to what it was.
2. Module: Clear out the module and set it back to what it was (even if it's empty).

If that doesn't fix it move on to checking the File Inspector (tab) > Interface Builder Document section

1. Opens In: Set it to Xcode 8
2. Builds for: Set it to your deployment target

Rinse and repeat for all XIB/storyboard files.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to solve your problem:

1. Open your project in Xcode (any 9.0 or 8.3.3)
2. Right 'Click' on story board.
3. Select 'Open As' >> 'Source Code'
4. find keyword 'minToolsVersion' (it may be more than one time) under 'dependencies'. (Look at below images)
5. Update value for minToolsVersion to 8.3, only where is it 9.0
6. Save and it's done.

Now you can open your storyboard in Xcode 8.x also.

[image]

[image]