# Xcode 12 Storyboard Identitiy Inspector can not find Class with iOS 12 Devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have an issue with a class which can not be found (see logs) when I try to run on iOS 12 Device. During exactly the run time, I receive an error in the console after app was launched on iOS 12 Device/Simulator:

> 2020-11-10 15:21:53.007203+0100 coreTest[36622:5293540] Unknown class
> _TtC8coreTest17WebViewController in Interface Builder file.

- The minimum iOS support for the project is iOS 12.
- The class is set in the Identitiy Inspector of the ViewController in Storyboard file.
- The class belongs to my app's target.
- I can navigate to this class pressing on the "arrow button" from the class name field of the Identitiy Inspector.

My custom class "WebViewController" is inherited from parent class which is marked as @objc.
I noticed, that in the console my class is written strange, so I added an @objc class name like

```
@objc(WebViewController) class WebViewController: MyParentClass
```

This did not help with the class naming.
I checked how the class is written in source code of the Storyboard - all is fine, the name is correct.

I have checked these questions : [Xcode 6 Bug: Unknown class in Interface Builder file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924966/xcode-6-bug-unknown-class-in-interface-builder-file) and [Unknown class in interface builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846538/unknown-class-in-interface-builder/44066778) . But the solutions did not help me.

BTW. With iOS 13 and 14 all is fine. No issues at all.

Is it a Xcode 12 specific for iOS 12 issue or I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm seeing the exact same behavior

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The decision was to update minimum supporting version to 13.